# testrpc install in windows

Tags: installation, nodejs, testrpc

I'm getting this error while installing testrpc:

```
 C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(34): error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\node_modules\secp256k1\build\secp256k1.vcxproj]
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Fallowed this steps[link] (https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/wiki/Installing-TestRPC-on-Windows)   every thing fine but finally installing testprc I got this error.